# SignalR OnDisconnected method never gets hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have implemented a widget so that a user can see what other users are on the website, or the page they are on. Everything works perfectly on my local box but when I deploy out to our test environment I can see (via some logging I put in place) that the OnConnected and several other methods are hit in my hub. However, when a user leaves the page the OnDisconnected method never gets hit. I've been monitoring for close to 2 hours closing and opening pages and only seeing the connections. All other events (and I have at least 3 of them running) occur. Our host uses IIS (and IIS Express on local). Is it maybe something I configured incorrectly on there? Here is a trace that includes the connection type. The traces are identical in both environments.[image: A trace of the connection]

Comment: Do you use virtual directory in your deployed server?

Comment: Yes I believe we are deployed under a virtual directory.